# How to call a helper method with & without html option

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm using a helper method as

```
 def edit(rad_visit, html_options = {})
   unless (rad_visit.cached_rad_status.status_name == "CANCELLED" || business_partner_signed_in?)
      link_to "Edit", edit_rad_visit_path(rad_visit.id), {:disable_with => "Please wait...", :class=>"btn btn-success"}
    end
  end
```

How can i to call this helper method in one page as`<%= edit(@rad_visit)%>`
     (without html option)
and in another page as
`<%= edit(@rad_visit)%>`
(with html option `{:disable_with => "Please wait...", :class=>"btn btn-success"}` )

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your helper to look like this:

```
def edit(rad_visit, html_options = {})
  unless (rad_visit.cached_rad_status.status_name == "CANCELLED" || business_partner_signed_in?)
    link_to "Edit", edit_rad_visit_path(rad_visit.id), html_options
  end
end
```

And then call it like this:

```
<%= edit(@rad_visit)%>
```

or

```
<%= edit(@rad_visit, {:disable_with => "Please wait...", :class=>"btn btn-success"})%>
```